# How to align text with Alignment package in Sublime 3 with spaces around '='?

Tags: alignment, sublimetext3

I want to use the Alignment package in Sublime Text 3 in order to align some variable assignments and I want to have spaces around the `=` character. This is an example:

```
bar = 'cherry'
bar_baz = 'tomato'
f = 'carrot'
```

This is how it turns out:

```
bar    = 'cherry'
bar_baz= 'tomato'
f      = 'carrot'
```

This is how it should be:

```
bar     = 'cherry'
bar_baz = 'tomato'
f       = 'carrot'
```

My settings for the Alignment package are the following:

```
{
    "alignment_chars": [
        "=", ":"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default settings show:

```
:
:
// The mid-line characters to align in a multi-line selection, changing
// this to an empty array will disable mid-line alignment
"alignment_chars": ["="],

// If the following character is matched for alignment, insert a space
// before it in the final alignment
"alignment_space_chars": ["="],
:
:
```

Confirm yours haven't been mangled somehow.

Using your input, if I select the text, or I use multiple cursors in front of `=`, and run the command it'll align as you specify, with spaces around `=`, like:

```
bar     = 'cherry'
bar_baz = 'tomato'
f       = 'carrot'
```

If I used multiple cursors, after running, the cursors are placed in front of the `=` still:

```
bar     |= 'cherry'
bar_baz |= 'tomato'
f       |= 'carrot'
```

So, the gist of this is, I can't duplicate your problem whether I change the `alignment_chars` or not.

I will recommend looking at the [AlignTab](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/AlignTab) package as a replacement for Alignment as the "Live Preview Mode" is great.

Comment: Thank you, it was the `"alignment_space_chars"` setting that was missing.